# INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: FileNotify|c|305

Tags: warning-messages

Does anybody know what this error means? Clicking the link in the warning message gives a "page not found", and Googling does not produce anything for this exact error code. I get it whenever I try to save a .m file. If, after saving for the first time, I try to save it again, *Mathematica* complains that the file has changed outside of *M*. If, however, I close the window and open the .m file again, all is good.

OS X 10.9, *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0

Comment: The same problem with the same version/OS, but no clue what it may be. Reported few times to W, no feedback...

Comment: I get these `INTERNAL SELF-TEST` errors from time to time, this usually clears it up http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464 so I've never taken the time to figure out exactly what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking Wolfram Support, they tell me this is a bug that has been fixed in version 10.1.